# display custom post type from register taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, loop

I've created a custom post type via this function:

```
function custom_post_type() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'advertising type', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'advertising type', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'advertising type', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent advertising', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All advertising', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View advertising', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New advertising', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit advertising', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update advertising', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search advertising', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    );


    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'advertising', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'description'         => __( 'advertising news and reviews', 'twentythirteen' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),

        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag') ,// this is IMPORTANT

        'capability_type'     => 'page',

    );
        register_taxonomy( 'advertising_type', 'advertising', $args );


    register_post_type( 'advertising', $args );

}



add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type', 0 );
```

Which include a taxonomy "advertising_type"

In my loop, I've ad the query post to display only post from a specific taxonomy:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array('post_type' => 'advertising', 'posts_per_page' => 50, 'advertising_type' => 'recruitment',
 ) );
query_posts( $args );
while(have_posts()): the_post();
?>



        <?php while ( $folio_loop->have_posts() ) : $folio_loop->the_post(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

which is recruitment using: `'advertising_type' => 'recruitment'`

However . . . I don't manage to make it work . . it doesn't display any post . . . If i delete this query I have the post from my custom post type display, so I imagine the problem is really coming from this ( That I can not display post from a specific taxonomy)

Any helps would be amazing,

thank you for your time and help guys

Comment: Never use `query_posts`, search this site for `pre_get_posts` action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'd like to note a few things wrong with your Post Type and Taxonomy set up. There's a few settings in your `$labels` that don't make sense:

```
$labels = array(
    ...
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
);
```

These last 4 options don't make much sense ( to me anyway ) when creating Post Type labels or Taxonomy labels. There'll never be a `$post->ID` set in the `init` function and `labels` is not the place where you would set a `post_type`, also `attachment` is a *reserved* / built-in post type so you can't reuse it. To view a full list of accepted Labels that you can use, follow the links below:

[Post Type Labels](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments)

[Taxonomy Labels](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments)

You'll notice that there's different labels for Taxonomy than there are Post Types. Along with a multitude of other settings, I wouldn't suggest you use the same arguments whenever you register taxonomy and post types but instead **create separate arguments for each**.

Assuming your Post Type and Taxonomy works, Milo is right ( in the comments section ) you shouldn't use `query_posts` and [Here's Why](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts). If you want you can create a [new WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) ( as mentioned above ).

**Use `pre_get_posts` To Modify The Main Query**

As said in the title, [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) will modify the main query before it actually gets outputted. This means that you can retain the `query_vars` that are ( presumably ) already set and you may overwrite anything you need. You would want to put this into your `functions.php` file, and it works like this:

[( Pre Get Posts Codex Article )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)

```
function advertising_pgp( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() ) {    // Do Not run on Admin Pages

        if( $query->is_main_query() ) {     // Only run on the Main Query

            $query->set( 'post_type', 'advertising' );
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 50 );
            $query->set( 'tax_query', array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'  => 'advertising_type',
                    'field'     => 'slug',
                    'terms'     => 'recruitment'
                )
            ) );

        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'advertising_pgp' );
```

***:: Warning ::*** The above will modify *all* main queries on your website. You may need to add additional conditional statements into the second conditional such as `is_page( 'Your-Page' )`

**Create a New WP Query**

WP Query is mostly used if you need an additional query to your main query. If you want to just modify your main query to something different, you can use `pre_get_posts` above, and since you're wanting to combine `query_vars` - I suggest `pre_get_posts` since it will already have them in there. I'll leave this here just in case.

```
global $wp_query;

$new_query = new WP_Query(
    array_merge( 
        $wp_query->query_vars,
        array(
            'post_type' => 'advertising',
            'posts_per_page' => 50, 
            'advertising_type' => 'recruitment'
        )
    )
);

<?php if( $new_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while( $new_query->have_posts() ) : $new_query->the_post(); ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```